# Including sqlite.db file in a WPF ClickOnce deployment

Tags: wpf, sqlite, clickonce

I built a small app with VS 2010 in WPF. I have used to store data in SQL lite. I have bound a dropdown field from SQL lite dataconnection.
When I run this application in VS it was worked fine. And published it as a click-once app. 
I have added SQL Lite.db file to application files and it appears in Project Properties ->
Publish tab -Application Files.

I set the file's Build Action to "Content", and in
Application files, set it to "Include".
But still the dropdown field doesn't have any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely the path to database gets lost. See [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx) - you need to make your sqlite file as `Data` (not `Content` as you did), and use `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` folder as a base folder for it.